# Insertar datos de un arreglo a mysql con php

Tags: php, javascript, java, mysql, pdo

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas el principal y el detalle. Tengo que registrar por ejemplo:

```
 Tabla 1  
 Idpersona persona  
  01       Juan

Tabla 2

ID idpersona pedido
1     01     zcahs
2     01     bitcoin
3     01     Eterium
```

Para insertar datos a la segunda tabla a los inputs defino como arreglos

```
<input name="pedido []" value="zcahs, bitcoin, eterium"/>
```

En el que el valor viene separado pos comas (,), como descifrar eso valores para que se inserten cada uno en una fila en la base de datos.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería más sencillo si se ahce asi:

form.php

Guardar

save.php

```
<?php
$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
$pedido = $_GET['pedido'];

//Utilizando PDO.

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password'); 
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Tabla1 (persona) VALUES(?)"); 
$dbh->beginTransaction(); 
$tmt->execute(array($nombre)); 
$dbh->commit(); 
$lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$parts = explode(",",$pedido);
foreach($parts as $part){
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Tabla2 (idpersona, pedido) VALUES(?,?)"); 
$dbh->beginTransaction(); 
$tmt->execute(array($lastId,$part)); 
$dbh->commit();
}

?>
```

Espero te funcione, saludos

Comment: Gracias, no me da ningun error pero no me registra algun error, aqui el codigo.